# Using Annotation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, annotation

I have produced an extensive set of annotation in ArcMap 10. I'm working with someone who basically has the need of a spatial database but only understands printed maps, so the text has grown to the point where I can't fit any more on the page. I'd like to export the annotation to a spreadsheet(no problem there) and replace the text shown on the page with an ID#. I'll then be left with a map with a bunch of small callouts which refer to a spreadsheet that my client knows how to work with. This annotation is not feature linked.

How do I change the display of my annotation feature class from the field titled 'TextString' to 'OBJECTID' or any other field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that no news is not good news in this case.

I don't think this can be done (outside of using feature linked annotation).

Comment: Brian- I think you're right.  My workaround was to copy the annotation feature class and then change the 'TextString' field to the value of the 'OBJECTID' field using the field calculator...not the most elegant of solutions but it worked.